# safari does not show iphone in the developer mode any more

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, safari

I am deploying an app from xcode and after an update to mac and iphone, the iphone does not show up anymore in safari developer mode.

the macos is on Sonoma 14.2
iphone is on 17.2 which is a iphone pro max
and xcode is version 15.1

I have tried restarting the devices etc but no luck.